# Can't install Django Osx

Tags: python, django, macos, python-3.x, pip

this appears when i try to install it:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django'
```

Comment: You are trying to install it globally. Don't do that; use a virtualenv.

Comment: either use sudo pip install or create a virtualenv with 755 permission and then install it in that virtualenv

Comment: Who the hell in the sane mind recommends installing django with sudo?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov Keep the language. It also one options to install the packages.

Comment: It's an option to install setuptools, wheel and pip. Period. Don't recommend installing third party globally with sudo.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I already installed virtualenv, how do I activate it?

Comment: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#usage

Comment: @chinbrows `. ./venv/bin/activate` from the directory on the same level where `venv` is.

Answer (score 1):

without a virtualenv use `pip install --user django`

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/